# how do I better setup the dice program to get a better output

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to create a dice program that rolls two dice 5 times and have each dice roll out its value and add the output combined total. I cant seem to get it to give me the combined total.

```
import random

min = 1
max = 6

def main():

     Reroll = 'y'


     while Reroll == 'y' or Reroll == 'Y':
         print('rollin...')
         print('you rolled:')
         print(random.randint(MIN, MAX))
         print(random.randint(MIN, MAX))

         again = input('Try for a higher roll? (y=yes):

main()
```

Here I edited the code and now it wont stop rolling

```
import random

MIN = 1
MAX = 6

def main():

     Reroll = 'y'
     while Reroll == 'y' or Reroll == 'Y':
         print('rollin...')
         print('you rolled:')
         die1 = random.randint(MIN, MAX)
         die2 = random.randint(MIN, MAX)
         total = die1 + die2
         print(die1)
         print(die2)
         print(die1, '+', die2, '=', total)

     again = input('Try for a higher roll? (y=yes)')

main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to *store* the output of the `random.randint()` functions first, not just print these:

```
 die1 = random.randint(MIN, MAX)
 die2 = random.randint(MIN, MAX)
 total = die1 + die2
 print(die1, '+', die2, '=', total)
```

You'll also have a problem with ending the loop, because you set the local name `again`, while testing the name `Reroll` instead. Because `Reroll` never changes, the loop will go on forever. Replace `again` with `Reroll`:

```
Reroll = input('Try for a higher roll? (y=yes)')
```

This needs to be indented to match the other lines *in* the loop!

Comment: where exactly because everywhere I seem to try to put this I get syntax error

Comment: Right after the 'you rolled' print. I fixed the syntax in your original question there, as there were errors in that too.

Comment: still giving me invalid syntax on this line    print(die1, '+', die2', '=', total)      its placing the cursor right before the =

Comment: @monkey: that's because there is a quote too many in the line. My apologies, fixed now.

Comment: @monkey: you set `again`, not `Reroll` in your loop.

Comment: @monkey: in your edited version, the `again` input line is *outside* of the `while` loop now.

Comment: sorry the site glitched on me and I had to redo the first code so it wasn't messed up then put up the second one for you to be able to see it .. for whatever reason it threw the second code I put up right in the middle of the first one.

Comment: @monkey: fixed your formatting once more. Select your code lines and use the *Code Sample* button on the edit toolbar to ensure that it is indented correctly to be displayed as code.

Comment: yep you were absolutely right it was the one line out of place causing the loop  thank you so much for your help